# POSTGRESQL - Error in returning select query

Tags: postgresql

Here is my function, which return error when executing this function:

```
create or replace function country(varchar) 

returns customer(customer_id integer,
                 first_name varchar,                       
                  last_name varchar) as $$


 select customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 

 from customer 

     inner join address on customer.address_id = address.address_id 
     inner join city on address.city_id = city.city_id 
     inner join country on city.country_id = country.country_id 

where country = '$1';

$$  
language sql;
```

Error occured in returning query.

Comment: I think you have a typo, you should be using `where country = $1`, _without_ the single quotes.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 2: returns customer(customer_id integer,                                       Thanks Tim I removed the single quotes but this error showed saying i have a syntax error and it points out the integer can you help me again please Im new to postgres

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "integer"
LINE 2: returns customer(customer_id integer                                                     Mureinik, thanks this is my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using create type for this solution:

```
create type ct as (customer_id integer, first_name varchar, last_name varchar)
```

now create function

```
create or replace function country(varchar) 

returns ct as $$

select customer_id, first_name, last_name from customer 
     inner join address on customer.address_id = address.address_id 
     inner join city on address.city_id = city.city_id 
     inner join country on city.country_id = country.country_id    
where country = $1;

$$ language sql;
```

Or Using this

```
create or replace function country(varchar) 

returns table(customer_id integer,
                 first_name varchar,                       
                  last_name varchar) as $$ 

 select customer_id, customer.first_name, customer.last_name 

 from customer 

     inner join address on customer.address_id = address.address_id 
     inner join city on address.city_id = city.city_id 
     inner join country on city.country_id = country.country_id 

where country = $1;

$$language sql;
```

Comment: Thank you Saddam I used your edited function but now its returning <unnamed portal 1> can you help me again?

Comment: dvdrental=# select country('Algeria');
      country       
--------------------
 <unnamed portal 6>
(1 row)
This the result I get

Comment: Are you are using cursor? which function you are using 1 or 2 (which i write above)

Comment: I just found out that i made another 'country' function with a cursor i dropped it and used your 2nd function Its working now Saddam many thanks for your help cheers!